# How To Join Two xPaths In One Single Collection?

Tags: list, xpath, html-agility-pack

var processorTitles = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='pad-hrz-xs']/a[@data-zone='title']");

var processorsPrices = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='card-v2-pricing']/p[@class='product-new-price']");

This will give me two diffrent Lists , I want to Combine This Two Xpaths , so that I can recive One Single List.

I , already tried something Like This : ("//div[@class='pad-hrz-xs']/a[@data-zone='title'] or //div[@class='card-v2-pricing']/p[@class='product-new-price']") , but nothing same result.

I , also tried  with " | " sign instead of "or" : ("//div[@class='pad-hrz-xs']/a[@data-zone='title'] | //div[@class='card-v2-pricing']/p[@class='product-new-price']") , but nothing same result.

I want to combine this two xPath , so that I will recive one single List.

Comment: the expression with `|` is valid XPath 1.0 so it's surprising that `SelectNode` doesn't work with it.

Comment: If you join the two sets with `|` (union) operator it will return a set of nodes that contains all the members of both sets, but NB any node which appeared in both sets will appear only once in the union set. What does your comment "nothing same result" mean?